# Exporting array to PHPExcel producing array to string conversion error

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpexcel

I'm using Codeigniter and PHPexcelTo try and write an array from a db result to an excel worksheet.

I have array made of the following data.

```
Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [ORDER] => 12334
        [DATE] => 2015-10-05
        [TEXT] => TEST
        [TIME] => 06:03:03
        [STATUS] => 1

    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [ORDER] => 99999
        [DATE] => 2015-10-05
        [TEXT] => TEST2
        [TIME] => 08:03:03
        [STATUS] => 0
    )
```

)

When I try to write the data to excel file using `phpexcel` I get the Object of class `stdClass` could not be converted to string error. 
I would like and excel file with the column names as `Order`,`Date`,`Text`,`Time` Status and the rows populated with the corresponding values.

Here is my current code

```
$this->load->library('excel');
    $this->excel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('test worksheet');
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->fromArray($ordersArray, NULL, 'A1');

    $filename='export.xls'; //save our workbook as this file name
    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel'); //mime type
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'.$filename.'"'); //tell browser what's the file name
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0'); //no cache

    //save it to Excel5 format (excel 2003 .XLS file), change this to 'Excel2007' (and adjust the filename extension, also the header mime type)
    //if you want to save it as .XLSX Excel 2007 format
    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($this->excel, 'Excel5');  
    //force user to download the Excel file without writing it to server's HD
    $objWriter->save('php://output');
```

I believe its an issue with the objects within the array but i'm unsure how to make it work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to cast the objects to arrays first, to make it a 2d-array:

```
array_walk(
    $ordersArray,
    function (&$row) {
        $row = (array) $row;
    }
);
$this->excel->getActiveSheet()->fromArray($ordersArray, NULL, 'A1');
```

Comment: thanks Mark, how would i get the column names in there?

Comment: You mean as a header row? You'd need to extract those keys separately using something like `$headers = array_keys($ordersArray[0]);` first and write that array to `A1`, then your actual `$ordersArray` to `A2`